# disable drag with touchscreen

Tags: windows

Hi not a programmer but am looking for advice. This is about how touchscreens interact with windows.
In many touch drivers that are provided with touchscreens they come with the ability to set up certain types of mouse mode. For example click on touch, click on release as well as the normal click and drag. I would like to know if there is a way (may be with a registry modification) that will turn the normally supplied windows function of ‘click and drag’ (the bit that draws the blue box on the desktop) into a click on touch that ignores any mouse_move . This will mean I can click on buttons but not drag the cursor around.
Welcome any options.
Kev

Comment: Which version of windows are you using? Also, why do you want to disable this feature? There might be an alternative solution to your original problem